# What are the statements in XNA?

Tags: xna-4.0

A hypothetical game called “AlienShooter” needs to be able to work on Windows and on the Xbox. In the Windows version, the keyboard will handle firing at alien spaceships, and this functionality is contained within a method called “KeyboardSupport()”. In the Xbox version of the game, the gamepad will be used for shooting, and this functionality is contained within a method called “GamepadSupport()”. Write the statement(s) that must be added so that the appropriate code is used in the each version of the game.

Comment: Really unclear. I had to look at the answer to figure out what the question was.

Comment: You know, [there are consequences to asking school/university assignment questions on stack exchange network](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161475/counting-and-generating-perfect-squares#comment11014758_4161475).

Comment: -1 You really couldn't even pose the question in your own words? Lack of research and I don't think "needing to do this homework problem" is "questions based on actual problems that you face."

Answer (score 2):

Use the [#if directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx):

```
#if WINDOWS
  KeyboardSupport();
#elif XBOX
  GamepadSupport();
#endif
```

The following symbols are defined for use in cross-platform compilation: `WINDOWS`, `XBOX or XBOX360` and `WINDOWS_PHONE`. See [Cross-Platform Conditional Compilation Symbols](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd282469.aspx) for further information.

Comment: @NikoDrašković I edited my answer to make it clearer. Thank you for your suggestion.